# Algorithm for finding weak (smallest diameter) connections in 2D and 3D objects

Tags: algorithm, matlab, image-processing, computer-vision

Following task: Assume you have been given a set of connected a) 2D points and b) 3D points. The task is, to find the n "weakest" connections in the points sets. That is, we want their location and strength. A weak connection is a separation of the object in several parts at places where the separating line / area is smalles, i.e. smallest diameter.

Example: Suppose you have two 3D objects (e.g. a machine that has a montior connected to it via an "arm"). I now want to be able to find this "arm-connection", be able to say where its weakast point is and how strong it is.

Another example is given in the image:

[image]

We see a 3D point cloud, where I have marked two "weak connections" with a red line - essentially that are the thinnest connections in the point cloud.

A 2D example could look like this:

[image]

where I again have marked the desired connection red.

How would you efficiently search for these connections?

What I could do is to consider the x closest neighbors for each point. If you take x large enough, the average distance to these neighbors will be very large at these thin connections. I however do not think that this would be a very fast and stable way to go. can you think of a better alternative?

Comment: Post an example image? Is it a binary image of solid areas? Also you should really define "weakest", do you just mean thinnest?

Comment: I would - 1. Try 2. Try more 3. If there's any problem, I would search for resources online/books/etc. 4. If there's any specific problem I might ask people on stackoverflow.

Comment: This is a image processing algorithmic problem and not an easy one too. It might fit better in another stackexchange for example in [Computer Science SE](http://cs.stackexchange.com/) although you also have some chances here given the large audience.

Comment: user18.. I defined weak in your question the way I understood it. If you do not agree, just edit your question.

Comment: @Trilarion in the future, please ask for clarification in the comments. I know it's easier to ask forgiveness, but edits are not allowed to change (and this means "add", too) information in the post.

Comment: @mabi Sorry, it was not my intent. Won't happen again.

Comment: @Trilarion no worries. I do think you got the meaning right, so I haven't rolled back the edit. In fact, the powers that be [encourage](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254562/785663) you to edit the question *after you posted an answer* (and probably got it accepted).

Comment: @Trilarion Yes, I believe your definition of "weak" makes sense :)

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is shrink the data set iteratively (shrinking means deleting points that have neighbours (horizontal or vertical) that do not belong to the object itself). Imagine this like peeling an onion. Everytime the onion get's smaller.

Now the important thing is that the weak connections will become thin (only one pixel wide) first. So you have to check in this iterative shrinking for sudden occurence of thin connections, i.e bridges between two parts. This is done in 2D by going around clockwise the pixel and checking how often you change from object to non-object. If you went more than once to non-object while going around, the pixel is a bridge.

Alternatively and for 3D I would do the shrinking even further and look for separated regions, because while shrinking your object will divide at the weakest connection. How to detect division? By filling. Use any filling algorithm.

How to do this in Matlab? I cannot make a full algorithm now, but you can follow the ideas above and I can recommend the free [Diplib](http://www.diplib.org/) for Matlab. I know it has shrinking of binary areas inbuilt although also without it is not too difficult.